# Как отключать компонент RigidBody2D при помощи скрипта?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как включать и отключать компонент RigidBody2D при помощи скрипта? Например объекты можно отключать setActive true или false. как это сделать с компонентом RigidBody2D?

Comment: `gameObject.GetComponent<RigidBody2D>().SetActive(false)` попробовали?

Comment: `RigidBody2D` вроде не отключается, даже в инспекторе галочки нет. Но тип тело можно сделать кинетический.

Answer (score 1):

Надо прописать это `gameObject.GetComponent<RigidBody2D>().SetActive(false)`. То есть всё практически как с объектами.